# how to search repeating paragraphs in a file using regular expression

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-3.5

I have an EDI file whose structure is given below. This file has multiple records, each record contains a header(e.g EDI.DD.0000000001.20130809), then contents (i.e multiple paragraphs of text) and then footer (e.g End of Report/No EDI Activity). I have to read that entire file using regular expression using three groups.

I am using following regular expression to read the file.

(?<1header>[A-Z]{3}.[A-Z]{2}.[0-9]{10}.[0-9]{8}) | (?<2footer> \b(End\sof\sReport|No\sEDI\sActivity)\b) |

(?<3content>(?<=\k<1header>).*(?=\k<2footer>))

That expression reads the "header" and "footer" in respective groups properly but didn't pick the contents between header and footer in "contents" group.

I have changed the font of header and footer in below file to help to understand the format.
I am using ASP.Net 3.5 framework.

Thanks for your help in advance.

//-------------------------Start of EDI File-----------------------------------------//

**EDI.DD.0000000001.20130809**

ORIGINATOR INFORMATION
   Company Name:              UNITED HEALTHCAR
   Identification:            9024125001
   Originating DFI:           002100002

RECEIVER INFORMATION
   Receiver Name:             HEALTH & WELLNESS
   DFI Account Number:        0000000000000001
   Receiving DFI ID:          434343430
   ID Number:
   Transaction Type:          22 Deposit

---

ORIGINATOR INFORMATION
   Company Name:              BLUE CHOICE
   Identification:            9024125001

**End of Report**

**EDI.DD.0006578987.20130809**

**No EDI Activity**

**EDI.SV.0000000555.20130809**

ORIGINATOR INFORMATION
   Company Name:              Univ of Florida
   Identification:            A426004813
   Originating DFI:           004200001

```
                TRANSACTION INFORMATION
```

Entry Description:         vndr pymnt
   Entry Class Code:          CTX
   Service Class Code:        ACH Entries Mixed

```
                    REMITTANCE ADVICE ACCOUNTS
                  RECEIVABLE OPEN ITEM REFERENCE
```

Seller's Invoice Number:   10016
   Pmt Action Code:
   Amount Paid:               $800.00
   Amount of Invoice:
   Amount of Discount:

**End of Report**

//-------------------------End of file--------------------------------------------------//

Comment: I begin to understand why Obamacare is late.

Answer (score 0):

When combined with the following options:

- **.NET**: `Multiline`, `Singleline` (sic)
- **OSX/iOS**: `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators`, `NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines`

try:

```
^(?<header>[A-Z]{3}.[A-Z]{2}.[0-9]{10}.[0-9]{8})$(?<content>.+?)^(?<footer>End\sof\sReport|No\sEDI\sActivity)$
```

Here's a **demonstration of the .NET solution** with the input date from the OP, via online .NET regexp tester [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net) (requires a browser with Silverlight):

http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=081cf97e-4c0b-4efb-b891-91f7cb03afb0

Comment: I tried your expression but it returns an empty string. I am using ASP .Net 3.5 and NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators and NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines are not available in it.

Comment: @user3415249: The question is tagged `nsregularexpression`, which implies OSX/iOS. You should add a `.NET` tag and also mention your environment in your question. I've updated my answer to provide a `.NET` solution, but I can't verify it at the moment - let me know if it works.

Comment: using multiline option gives me same result i.e an empty string.

Comment: @user3415249: Seems to work here - although I can't tell what .NET version is being used: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=081cf97e-4c0b-4efb-b891-91f7cb03afb0 - http://regexhero.net is a very handy .NET online regex tester I just stumbled upon.